# sharing folders with passwords

Tags: linux, network-share

I have a Linux box which should share a few directories to other systems over the LAN.
The other systems are running linux as well.

I'd like to associate a different password for each folder without creating different users. Is there a way to achieve that?

Feel free to put NFS and SSH combos into the mix. The key point is that I need different passwords for different directories, like this:

EXPORTED DIR: /opt/dir1       PASSWORD:   'foo'

EXPORTED DIR: /usr/lib/dir2   PASSWORD:   'bar'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samba can do this with share level passwords. Each directory would be a different share with its own password defined in smb.conf.

Comment: +1. NFS isn't capable of password-based authentication unless you're using NFSv4 with Kerberos authentication. You almost certainly want to be using Samba.